# ASP.NET MVC: Hidden form field not accepting new value from model after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view I currently have the following code:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("Cart.CartID", Model.Cart.CartID) %>
```

When the page initially loads, CartID  is null so when I view source on the page the value is set to "". When I submit the form on the page (adding a product), the controller code will create a new cart and using a strongly typed viewmodel, I pass the cart back into the view with a CartID. The problem is that the value for the hidden form field doesn't get updated with the new value.

I have verified that I am indeed passing back a Cart instance complete with CartID on the post.

Here is some of the controller code. The controller is called Orders and the view is called Create:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "AddProduct")]
public ActionResult Create(Product product, Cart cart, Customer customer)
{
    if (cart.CartID == null)
    {
        Guid _cartIdentifier;
        _cartIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
        var _newCart = new Cart() { CartIdentifier = _cartIdentifier, CartDate = DateTime.Now };
        cart = _cartRepository.Add(_newCart);
    }

    var _cartItem = new CartItem() { CartID = cart.CartID, ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(product.ProductID) };
    _cartRepository.Add(_cartItem);

    var _cartItems = _cartRepository.GetCartItems(new CartItem() { CartID = cart.CartID });

    var viewState = new GenericViewState
    {
        Cart = cart,
        CartItems = _cartItems
    };        

    return View(viewState);
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? How do I go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see some of your controller?

Comment: Updated the post with controller code.

Comment: What does `GenericViewState` look like?

Comment: @Mike, Yes, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594600/possible-bug-in-asp-net-mvc-with-form-values-being-replaced

Comment: Dan, That was it. I used the regular HTML Hidden field instead of the helper and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I never did receive a reply from Phil Haack about this though, but I do see it as a bug in MVC.

Comment: Had the same problem and it's fixed now that I'm not using the Html.HiddenFor helper anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a new `Html.Hidden` extension which basically overrode what the default one did.

Quick example below.

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
  public static string Hidden(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value)
  {
    return string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" />", helper.Encode(name), helper.Encode(value.ToString()));
  }
}
```