# Updating viewmodel data in controller doesn't reflect in view's input fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a blogpost edit page where you can either save your edits or upload an image (multiple submits in a single form). When you upload an image, the image link gets appended to a TinyMCE content area.

The fields for the form are in a viewusercontrol(shared with create page). Both the viewpage and usercontrol inherit from `BlogPost` so the model's being passed directly using `<% Html.RenderPartial("Fields", Model); %>`

So here's the weird thing; in my controller, when I append the image link to the textarea, nothing happens to the textarea in the view

On my viewpage I have a label for `Model.Title` and within the usercontrol I have the textbox for editing `Model.Title`.

If I update the label in the controller - `model.Title = "New Title"` - the updated model data changes for the label in the viewpage but not the textbox in the usercontrol.

My Controller is like this:

```
// /edit/{id}
public ViewResult Edit(int id, BlogPost model, string submit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            switch (submit)
            {
                case "Upload":
                    var files = UploadFiles(Request.Files); // uploading works

                    model.Content += files[0].Link; // model is updated but not cascaded at runtime
                    model.Title = "Test"; // Force a title change to reproduce the issue
                    return View(model);

                default:
                    repository.Update(model);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this and how to fix it? Thanks.

- I am using 4.0 and MVC 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this behaviour is by design and has been answered by Phil Haack here:

[Possible bug in ASP.NET MVC with form values being replaced.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594600/possible-bug-in-asp-net-mvc-with-form-values-being-replaced)

There's also a blog post about this here:

[ASP.NET MVC’s Html Helpers Render the Wrong Value!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx)

For my scenario (appending an image to tinymce), I think it's safe to clear the ModelState because we're explicitly appending to a textarea and not doing any validation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that there is code in the top level view that is changing the value of Model.Title before the RenderPartial is called?

Comment: Nope, the top viewpage only has the html form helper, RenderPartial and the Model.Title display.