# Problem with HiddenFor helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
public sealed class Model
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Model { Value = "+" } );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Model model)
    {
        model.Value += "1";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm()){%>
  <%: Model.Value %>
  <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Value) %>
  <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
<%}%>
```

Every time I submitted form result is

```
<form action="/" method="post">+1
<input id="Value" name="Value" type="hidden" value="+">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

It means that HiddenFor helper doesn't use real value of Model.Value but uses passed to controller one. Is it bug in MVC framework? Does anyone know workaround?

UPDATE:
EditerFor works similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594600/possible-bug-in-asp-net-mvc-with-form-values-being-replaced

Comment: I have posted an explanation of the issue: **why isn't it by design that the Model is used, which is set explicitly by the developer and if a validation error occurred, the ModelState is used** And a really simple and effective solution to fix this issue exactly wihout using weird workarounds. [possible-bug-in-asp-net-mvc-with-form-values-being-replaced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594600/possible-bug-in-asp-net-mvc-with-form-values-being-replaced/30698787#30698787)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will fix your problem, however it's not a recommended solution.

More info can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    model.Value += "1";

    ModelState.Clear();

    return View(model);
}
```

[Edit]

Another option if you don't want to use `<input id="Value" name="Value" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.Value %>"/>`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    var m = new Model();

    m.Value = collection["Value"] + "1";

    return View(m);
}
```

Comment: Did you even read the article? Use `<input id="Value" name="Value" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.Value %>"/>` instead of `ModelState.Clear();`

Comment: Well, if you clear the ModelState you get rid of all the data that was entered by users when there are some errors. What is wrong with HTML in HTML?

Comment: Bad is that we can't use useful helper methods. It means that we should generate id and name attributes by oneself, for example.